# Wrong Gateway IP assigned, randomly

Tags: networking, router, gateway

I'm having some issues with my local network.

I get my internet at home via an external 4G antenna. Signal comes in via a small POE passive injector like this:

[image]

From that a single ethernet port goes into my router (TP LINK TD-W8960N (http://www.tp-link.com.au/products/details/cat-15_TD-W8960N.html)). The cable goes into the LAN4/WAN port.

[image]

To this router I connect with various wifi devices and some other devices connect via cable into the router.

The POE injector sits on 192.168.1.1, and that cannot be changed. The router is 192.168.1.254.

The problem...

IP's get automatically assigned, but randomly it seems the Gateway IP gets switched between the router & the POE injector. When it's the POE injector, everything works fine. So when devices assign 192.168.1.1 as the gateway ip everything works, but randomly, for example after rebooting a pc, 192.168.1.254 will be assigned as the Gateway IP, and then the internet doesn't work. It's really odd, as half the time after a restart it works, other times it doesn't. If I manually put the IP's on every device it works fine, but I want this to work automatically.

How should I setup my TP router to always pass along the right Gateway IP?

Comment: PoE devices don't have their own IP addresses - they're just used to add power to an Ethernet to power a PoE device where there is no power outlet near the device to be powered. I would also look at reconfiguring your LAN to use a different subnet to that of your incoming Internet. E.g. 192.168.2.x.

Comment: You need to find out which devices in your network act as DHCP servers, and which DHCP servers you actually need. Most likely your 4G modem also acts as a DHCP server.